# can't run this command from outside of powershell7, default powershell works

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, cmd, powershell-7.0

{Oh if possible I don't want to use powershell}
I've a pc where powershell default is broken so I'm forced to use ps7,
if I run this

```
import subprocess
import os

powershell = ''
if os.path.isfile('C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe'):
    powershell = 'pwsh'
elif os.path.isfile('C:/Program Files (x86)/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe'):
    powershell = 'pwsh'
else:
    powershell = 'powershell'

filename = 'test.exe'

subprocess.call(powershell + ' curl -H '+'\'Authorization: token ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\''+' -H '+'\'Accept: application/vnd.github.v4.raw\''+' -o ' + filename + ' https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxxxx/[repo]/[branch]/'+filename+'\'', shell=True)
```

it says

```
The argument 'curl' is not recognized as the name of a script file. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

but if I run this

```
curl.exe -H 'Authorization: token ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v4.raw' -o test.exe https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[user]/[repo]/[branch]/test.exe
```

command in ps7 directly, it works,

I also tried running this in command prompt

```
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" curl.exe -H 'Authorization: token ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v4.raw' -o test.exe https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[user]/[repo]/[branch]/test.exe
```

and got same error

Comment: Consider using `requests` from python?

Comment: um . . .  how do I do that?? can you please tell?? idk how

Comment: There is a simpler solution. I think you are just intending to download a single file from GitHub. Maybe you can just use this: https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home

Comment: it's private repo and need to put it inside my python script, and if I want to download from github I can just download it from there, don' t need these sites tho, so if you know how to do it with requests can you please tell me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can use the requests module from python.

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "Authorization": "token ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v4.raw",
}
#### for file less than 1 mb
response = requests.get(
    "https://api.github.com/repos/[INSERT_OWNER_HERE]/[INSERT_REPO_HERE]/contents/[PATH/TO/FILE]", headers=headers
)
### If file is more than 1MB 
response = requests.get(
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[INSERT_OWNER_HERE]/[INSERT_REPO_HERE]/[BRANCH]/[PATH/TO/FILE]", headers=headers
)
with open("test.exe", "wb") as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

And this is how to do it with powershell and subprocess

```py
import os
import subprocess

powershell = ""
if os.path.isfile("C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe"):
    powershell = "pwsh"
elif os.path.isfile("C:/Program Files (x86)/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe"):
    powershell = "pwsh"
else:
    powershell = "powershell"
filename = "test.exe"
subprocess.call(
    powershell
    + " -Command curl.exe -H "
    + "'Authorization: token []'"
    + " -H "
    + "'Accept: application/vnd.github.v4.raw'"
    + " -o "
    + filename
    + " https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[INSERT_OWNER_HERE]/[INSERT_REPO_HERE]/[BRANCH]/"
    + filename,
    shell=True,
)
```

Comment: bro this is file link `https://github.com/WoLvES-2x0/tags/blob/main/test.exe`
how do I put it here?? `https://api.github.com/repos/INSERT_OWNER_HERE/INSERT_REPO_HERE/contents/PATH/TO/FILE`

Comment: Possibly this way https://api.github.com/repos/WoLvES-2x0/tags/contents/test.exe

Comment: `https://api.github.com/repos/WoLvES-2x0/tags/contents/main/test.exe`
`https://api.github.com/repos/WoLvES-2x0/tags/contents/test.exe`
`https://api.github.com/repos/WoLvES-2x0/tags/main/test.exe`
these doesn't work

Comment: {"message":"This API returns blobs up to 1 MB in size. The requested blob is too large to fetch via the API, but you can use the Git Data API to request blobs up to 100 MB in size.","errors":[{"resource":"Blob","field":"data","code":"too_large"}],"documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content"}

Comment: Could you substitute it with as the way you initially used it with curl: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[user]/[repo]/[branch]/test.exe

Comment: I used this before but had same problem
`from urllib import parse\n
from github import Github\n
import base64\n
g = Github("")\n
repo = g.get_user().get_repo('tags')\n
content_test = repo.get_contents(parse.quote('test.exe'), ref="main").content\n
all_test_bytes = base64.b64decode(content_test)\n
print(content_test)`

Answer (score 1):

Not so difficult with PowerShell if you have to

```
$headers = @{Authorization = "token ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxx";Accept = "application/vnd.github.v4.raw"}
$URL = "https://github.com/WoLvES-2x0/tags/blob/main/test.exe"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Headers $headers
```

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt try

```
cd [script location]
```

If you have python as a language on your PC then you should just be able to do:

```
python [script name].py
```

and it should run, if not just try re-installing power-shell and python.

Comment: well I think you didn't understand my question, although I want to execute this from python, for now python doesn't matter as the problem lies in powershell7

Comment: depends, if your able to run the code via command prompt then you know the code is not the thing causing an error, sometimes powershell7 will not work if the code has any errors in it, its always best to check paths first, incase, as it is the most common error that people encounter.

Comment: @WoLvES2.0 try adding -c switch and surrounding the whole command with double quotes `'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe' -c "curl.exe -H 'Authorization: token ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v4.raw' -o test.exe https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[user]/[repo]/[branch]/test.exe"`

Comment: @daniel ya figured out after sometimes that I need to use command parameter, but I was waiting for more python friendly way instead of powershell